Serverless Framework: Point to a pre-existing Lambda function from a REST API Gateway
I referred to this question. It's still unanswered. Isn't there a way at all to directly point to a pre-existing Lambda function from serverless.yml while creating a new REST API Gateway?
From the referred question, it could ideally be like this:
functions:
someFunction:
    arn: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:...
    events:
        - http:
            ...

